# Do Notification Hub active devices ever become inactive?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

One of the pricing points for Notification Hubs is "active devices". Active devices are defined as follows on the [pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/):

> Active devices are devices eligible to receive notifications. They are defined as unique registration IDs for devices using Google Cloud Messaging or Amazon Device Messaging, channel uniform resource identifiers (URI) for devices using Windows notification service or Microsoft push notification Service, or device tokens for devices using Apple push notification service.

Our application (iOS with APNS and Android with FCM) registers new devices as users install the app, however, we never unregister devices.

Do Notification Hubs manage what is defined as an active device? For example, if someone starts using our app and their device is registered, however, they uninstall the app a week later. Will this device ever become inactive or will I always be paying for it even though it no longer exists? If Notification Hubs does not manage "active" devices for me, how can I properly define and clean up old devices that are no longer in use so that I am not continually paying for them?

Answer (score 0):

After spending quite a while digging into this, it looks like device registrations/installations will stick around until they expire and I would assume are therefore considered an active device.  According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management#installations registrations and installations default to never expire. So you may need to start setting the ExpirationTime when you create a registration or installation.

Alternatively it looks like you can set a default Time To Live for Registrations on a per-hub basis according to
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/push-notification-hub-telemetry-expiry-update/

Comment: Thanks for the info. So what would be the process for handling an installation after it expires? What is the installation is still being actively used?

Comment: The second link says that they "recommend updating registrations and installations for devices on app startup." So I would suggest they probably want us to perform some sort of sliding TTL there where we update it to X days from the time at app startup.